# Is there any way to fit a slide Nav in splitter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to fit a slide nav on the right side of the splitter, which is able to split when dragging the separator based on the width of the right side. https://jsfiddle.net/74bewsdu/
I tried modifying the width to auto as well as the z-index, it still doesn't work well.

**index**

```
<div class="splitter">
  <div id="first">
    <iframe src="{{ route('child') }}" style="width:100%; height:100%" frameBorder="0">
      Your browser isn't compatible
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="separator"></div>
  <div id="second">
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav"></div>
    <div style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}
```

**css**

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: where the ```<div class="splitter">``` is getting closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the `offsetWidth` of the right side div (`#second`) plus the `offsetWidth` of the separator, and set the sliding nav width to that value. If you don't want to completely overlap the menu button, you could subtract it by the width of the menu button (or some arbitrary constant).

Example (see comments in lines between `/* added */` and `/* end added */` areas in the snippet below). Update: I also added code to check to see if the slider nav is open. Now, if you drag the slider when the side nav is open, it should be dynamically resized.

```js
let navIsOpen = false;  // variable to keep track of if the slider nav is open
function openNav() {
  /* added */
  // calculate width of right side div + separator
  let width = second.offsetWidth + separator.offsetWidth;
  // uncomment below line to subtract a value so the slider doesn't obscure the menu button/text
  //width = width - 95;
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = width + "px";
  navIsOpen = true;  // slider nav is open
  /* end added */
}


// function is used for dragging and moving
function dragElement(element, direction) {
  var md; // remember mouse down info
  const first = document.getElementById("first");
  const second = document.getElementById("second");
  element.onmousedown = onMouseDown;

  element.onmousedown = onMouseDown;

  function onMouseDown(e) {
    //console.log("mouse down: " + e.clientX);
    md = {
      e,
      offsetLeft: element.offsetLeft,
      offsetTop: element.offsetTop,
      firstWidth: first.offsetWidth,
      secondWidth: second.offsetWidth
    };
    first.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    document.onmousemove = onMouseMove;
    document.onmouseup = () => {
      //console.log("mouse up");
      document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
    }
  }

  function onMouseMove(e) {
    //console.log("mouse move: " + e.clientX);
    var delta = {
      x: e.clientX - md.e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY - md.e.clientY
    };

    if (direction === "H") // Horizontal
    {
      // prevent negative-sized elements
      delta.x = Math.min(Math.max(delta.x, -md.firstWidth),
        md.secondWidth);

      element.style.left = md.offsetLeft + delta.x + "px";
      first.style.width = (md.firstWidth + delta.x) + "px";
      second.style.width = (md.secondWidth - delta.x) + "px";
    }
    /* added */
    if (navIsOpen) {  // check if slider nav is open, if so resize
        openNav();
    }
    /* end added */
  }
}


dragElement(document.getElementById("separator"), "H");
```

```css
.splitter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

#separator {
  cursor: col-resize;
  background-color: #aaa;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='30'><path d='M2 0 v30 M5 0 v30 M8 0 v30' fill='none' stroke='black'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  /* prevent browser's built-in drag from interfering */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#first {
  background-color: #dde;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 10px;
}

#second {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 10px;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="splitter">
  <div id="first">
    <iframe src="{{ route('child') }}" style="width:100%; height:100%" frameBorder="0">
            Your browser isn't compatible
            </iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="separator"></div>
  <div id="second">
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav"></div>
    <div style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</div>
  </div>
</div>
```